# matplotlib - Change text colour on bar chart labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which I use to do a stacked bar plot, and then plot the percentage labels on the bars as text:

```
dfLev = pd.DataFrame({"year":['2017/16','2015/16','2014/15','2013/14','2012/13', '2011/12', '2010/11'],
                    "a":[1158,1091,1029,1062,929,922,725], 
                    "b":[3713,3319,3395,3773,3684,4215,4177]})


df_total = [4871,4410,4424,4835,4613,5137,4902]

dfLevFinal = dfLev.iloc[:, 0:3]


plotBar = dfLevFinal.plot(x = 'year', kind='barh',stacked = True, color = ['#8C4799','#008275'], title = '', mark_right = True)

df_rel = dfLevFinal[dfLevFinal.columns[1:3]].div(df_total, 0)*100

#plot the labels on the bars
for n in df_rel:
    for i, (cs, ab, pc) in enumerate(zip(dfLevFinal.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(1)[n], dfLevFinal[n], df_rel[n])):
        plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(int(np.round(pc))) + '%', va='center', ha='center')
```

However,  the labels on the bars are in 'black' font, which is difficult to see. How do I change it to 'white'?

I have tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.color'] = 'White'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It was a simple fix:

I added `color = 'white'` to the bottom line:

```
#plot the labels on the bars
for n in df_rel:
    for i, (cs, ab, pc) in enumerate(zip(dfLevFinal.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(1)[n], dfLevFinal[n], df_rel[n])):
        plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(int(np.round(pc))) + '%', va='center', ha='center', color = 'white')
```